# How to encode a unique board position?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, puzzle

How can I encode a unique board position? Reflections and rotations of a particular board position are not considered unique. For example, the positions below are the same:[Board positions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSB5X.png)
My idea was to assign a weightage of 1-4 for each row, the total "weight" of an L-piece would be the sum of the weight of the squares covered by the L-piece. For example, the following L-piece has a weight of 12: [Weight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh2iu.png)
How should I proceed from here? Or is there another idea for this?
I look forward to reading your answer and sorry if the post is off-topic.

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. Are you looking for a way to encode game states (eg an injective map from game states to integers)? What does it mean for such an encoding to "include rotating and mirroring the pieces"?

Comment: @stewbasic I have edited the question, is it clearer now? And to answer your question, yes I am looking an injective map from game states to integers which is not affected by rotations or reflections of the board,

Comment: It would be great if the question was self contained. What is a board? What is a board position? What is an L-piece? And why is this philosophy?

Comment: cannot you just assig 1 to occupied cells and 0 to free ones? Then read the 16-digit binary number row by row. You can convert it to decimal if needed

Comment: Why does your example have a weight of 12?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is indeed a good idea to code each square individually, and to then encode pieces on the basis of the codes of the squares they occupy, so you are on the right track.  However, because you want the function value to be invariant to mirroring and rotation, I suggest that you encode each square that is the 'same' relative to mirroring and rotation with the same code, e.g.:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&2&2&1\\
\hline
2&3&3&2\\
\hline
2&3&3&2\\
\hline
1&2&2&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

Now, to encode an L-piece, we can code an ordered 4-tuple (the order reflecting a path through the squares occupied by the piece) e.g. to encode the piece you have as an example:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&2&2&1\\
\hline
\color{red}2&\color{red}3&3&2\\
\hline
\color{red}2&3&3&2\\
\hline
\color{red}1&2&2&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

we would code $<1,2,2,3>$, which can be done in various ways, but one way would be to concatenate their two-bit binary numbers into an 8-bit number, e.g. $<1,2,2,3>$ becomes $01101011$, or $107$ in decimal.

Note that the order is important, since if you just pick 4 numbers, say 2,2,3,3, then there are 2 different L-piece positions that are like that:

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&2&2&1\\
\hline
\color{red}2&\color{red}3&\color{red}3&2\\
\hline
\color{red}2&3&3&2\\
\hline
1&2&2&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
1&2&2&1\\
\hline
\color{red}2&\color{red}3&3&2\\
\hline
2&\color{red}3&3&2\\
\hline
1&\color{red}2&2&1\\
\hline
\end{array}

But with the ordering, these two pieces become $<2,2,3,3>$ and $<2,3,3,2>$ respectively, and hence can be distinguished.

Finally, $<3,2,2,1>$ obviously describes the same piece/position as $<1,2,2,3>$, but to make sure the function is injective, we can simply insist on only using the code that results the lower number, so we would never use $<3,2,2,1>$, but instead use $<1,2,2,3>$. Likewise, we would use $<2,1,2,2>$ but not $<2,2,1,2>$